# MAMP 3.4 immediately crashes upon launch

Tags: mamp

Fresh install. OSX 10.10.5. I found a post several years old that mentioned a solution of making sure 127.0.0.1 (null) was not in /etc/hosts. No effect.

Here's a dump of the error:

```
Process:               MAMP [2867]
Path:                  /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP
Identifier:            de.appsolute.MAMP
Version:               3.4 (3.4)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MAMP [2867]
User ID:               962435817

Date/Time:             2015-11-09 11:29:13.754 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1021)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        C3B21FD3-E569-950C-7452-43A3D5CEDC99


Time Awake Since Boot: 1300 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100015000 [   84K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   de.appsolute.MAMP               0x0000000100006a6b 0x100000000 + 27243
1   de.appsolute.MAMP               0x0000000100006d7a 0x100000000 + 28026
2   de.appsolute.MAMP               0x0000000100008b84 0x100000000 + 35716
3   de.appsolute.MAMP               0x000000010000313d 0x100000000 + 12605
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff887be45c
```

Comment: Same here.  Started after updating my core system PHP to 5.5... which should be completely unrelated.

Comment: I switched to AAMPS. Works without issue and has some nice additional features.

Comment: Updated to 3.5 and working successfully now.  Having a little trouble with port 80 already taken up the mac by default.